# function onClick not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, onclick, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a django admin site where an admin can manage the documents that the employees are allowed to see. The admin can change the order of the elements because I added the class "sortable" in the ul that contains the document elements, in the following way:

```
<!-- Sortable categories and documents -->
<div class="document_container">
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li class="document-item context-menu-document"></li>
        <li class="document-item context-menu-document"></li>
        <li class="document-item context-menu-document"></li>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, using a JS I'm attaching a click event to the elements that has the class .document-item in order to select them, as you can see:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.document-item').click(function(e){
        $(this).addClass('ui-selected selected-unique');
    });
});
```

Until here, everything works as expected.

Now, I also want the employees to be able to enter in the admin site, but they cannot change the order of the elements. To do so, I have changed the line:

```
<ul class="sortable">
```

For the line:

```
<ul>
```

Indeed, the users cannot move the elements now, but it seems that the click behaviour is not working either. The funciton is attached to the elements, as I can see in the inspector, but is never triggered.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that your code should work. Maybe provide a plunkr or an editable example? Maybe you have some css that prevents click action (something like pointer-events:none;)?

Comment: The problem is not caused by the missing `class="sortable"`. It has to be some other change.

Comment: @skoll Do you think it can be some "event.preventDefault"? I'm looking into it now. I checked the "pointer-events: none" as Daniel said but those didn't cause any issue.